# How can i change the output to a single list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def purify(num):
    for number in num:
        if number%2 == 0:
            number = list(str(number))
            print(number)


purify([1,8,9,6,5,3,4,6,5,8,8,9,9,2,3,1,5])
```

**o/p - ['8']['6']['4']['6']['8']['8']['2']**

I am trying to remove all the odd numbers from the list, I have converted all the numbers into strings but after printing I get multiple lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is it done in the same way:

```
num = [1,8,9,6,5,3,4,6,5,8,8,9,9,2,3,1,5]
newlist = [str(i) for i in num if i%2==0]
print(newlist)
```

It gives the o/p like this:

```
['8', '6', '4', '6', '8', '8', '2']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def purify(num):
    even = []
    for number in num:
        if number%2 == 0:
            even.append(str(number))
    print("['{}']".format("']['".join(even)))
```

Then

```
>>> purify([1,8,9,6,5,3,4,6,5,8,8,9,9,2,3,1,5])
['8']['6']['4']['6']['8']['8']['2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def purify(num):
    newlist=[]
    for number in num:
        if number%2 == 0:
            number = str(number)
            newlist.append(number)
    print(newlist)
    return newlist
```

Try this. You needed a list to store the numbers. Output:

```
['8', '6', '4', '6', '8', '8', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you last result is odd numbers then you could try :

```
ls=[1,8,9,6,5,3,4,6,5,8,8,9,9,2,3,1,5]
print(list(filter(lambda x:not x%2,ls)))
```

output:

```
[8, 6, 4, 6, 8, 8, 2]
```

If you want in the string:

```
[['8'], ['6'], ['4'], ['6'], ['8'], ['8'], ['2']]
```